# Add event to mysql database with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, fullcalendar

I can't add the event title that I entered through the popup box.

I have this jquery code where I placed my ajax code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 var date = new Date();
 var d = date.getDate();
 var m = date.getMonth();
 var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({                
        editable: true,
        events: "http://localhost/test/events.php",
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
         var title = prompt('Event Title:');
         if (title) {

         /*
         start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
         end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
         $.ajax({
         url: 'http://localhost/test/add_events.php',
         data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end ,
         type: "POST",
         success: function(json) {
         alert('OK');
         }
         });
         */

         calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
         {
         title: title,
         start: start,
         end: end,
         allDay: allDay
         },
         true // make the event "stick"
         );
         }
         calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        }
    });

});
```

then I have this add_events.php where the insert query is written

```
    <?php

    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $start=$_POST['start'];
    $end=$_POST['end'];

    // connect to the database
     try {
     $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fullcalendar', 'root', '');
     } catch(Exception $e) {
     exit('Can not connect to the database.');
     }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO evenement (title, start, end) VALUES (:title, :start, :end)";
    $q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':start'=>$start, ':end'=>$end));
    ?>
```

I commented a code snippet from my default.html because I think this is where the problem lies. When I comment this code snippet, I can add an event through a popup box and after confirming the event title, the event title will be plainly visible in my fullCalendar(but not yet added in the database). But if I "uncomment" that section, the typed event title through the popup box does not appear in my fullCalendar(and obviously, it is not yet added in my database)

Can someone help me edit my ajax code so that I can make the typed event title through the popup box appear in my fullCalendar and be succesfully added in my database.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think your bug is in your Ajax call and the way you set your data in post call.

Your data attribute should be like this:

```
var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
var title = "Title name";
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://localhost/test/add_events.php',
   data: {
      title: title, 
      start: start,
      end: end
   },
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {
      alert('OK');
   }
});
```

Comment: same problem occurs. still, the inputted event title does not appear in my fullcalendar